# Why is there a discrepancy between disks and df?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I'm using Ubuntu Bionic Beaver - Development Branch. I have a 1TB SATA hard drive.

I partitioned the drive using Gparted thus:
part 1: 26GB FAT,
part 2: 948GB Ext4,
part 3: 26GB Swap.

When I use the 'Disks' application which comes as default with the Ubuntu OS, it displays the disk usage as I have outlined. When I run df -h in a terminal (some output omitted):

/dev/sda1: 25GB (/boot/efi); 
 /dev/sda2: 868GB (/)

/dev/sda3 is not included in the df -h output, which is fine, but why the huge difference where the second  (ext4, /dev/sda2) partition is concerned? My HP laptop is three years old and originally came with windows 8 pre-installed. I've wiped the whole drive a bunch of times, had countless Linux distros installed, but prior to installing a new OS I routinely create a new partition table and new partitions. This isn't something new to this iteration of Ubuntu; I've noticed it in the past. Please note that I have accounted for disk usage; the full size - as opposed to available - of part 2 according to Disks is 868GB. Running df -h tells me its 948GB. Why is that?

Comment: Use `df -k` to display 1K block size, The -h option (human readable) displays 1024K block size.

Comment: @stumblebee: thank you; that is an interesting point to note. However, df -k shows /dev/sda2 to be 909983984 (1K-blocks).  Still not near 948GB. The discrepancy remains.

Comment: Disks is also showing raw disk space but there is overhead involved when you create a filesystem.

Comment: See my answer below, but remember that some tools measure blocks used, others "real" bytes, yet others include "holes".  For example, a mostly unused virtual disk file will be reported differently by different tools.  If it's a 10G vdisk, some tools will report 10G used, other will report actual blocks used <-- that's the "holes" part.  All the best! -m

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR they are measuring different things

Longer version:

Storage usage on Linux file systems (any file system really) is actually very complicated.  I recommend Googling for differences in `df` and `du` for some classic examples of tools measuring different things that a novice (not criticizing, we all have to learn) might think should be the same.

Here is a good example.  Say you notice you are low on space by checking with both `du` and `df` and they match.  Great!  Then you delete a large file and check again.  If a process has a handle to that file you will now see different results.  `du` will no longer see the file and immediately reflect the change.  `df` will only show the difference once the process accessing the file terminates.

I also recommend playing with `lsof`.  Under the covers all these tools use various strategies and rules for determining "usage" because they are solving different problems, and that's useful once you understand their intents.  The `disks` application is the same in that it is making assumptions about the definition of "used space" and therefor gives results accordingly.

Hope that helps!